# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 180: invalid start byte

Tags: mysql, django, amazon-rds, mysql-python, django-mysql

I'm using Django with below config in settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '-',
        'USER': '-',
        'PASSWORD': '-',
        'HOST': '-',
        'PORT': '-',
        'OPTIONS': {'charset': 'utf8mb4'}
    }
}
```

The db server is running on AWS RDS. I have two EC2 instances, one of them is able to run the exact same code and fetch same data while from the second EC2 I'm getting this error:

```
     return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql  params  many=False  executor=self._execute)
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/python39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py"   line 75  in _execute_with_wrappers  
     return executor(sql     params  many    context)
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/python39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py"   line 84  in _execute    
     return self.cursor.execute(sql  params)        
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/python39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py"  line 73  in execute 
     return self.cursor.execute(query    args)      
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/python39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py"    line 206     in execute 
     res = self._query(query)           
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/python39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py"    line 321     in _query  
     self._post_get_result()            
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/python39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py"    line 355     in _post_get_result    
self._rows = self._fetch_row(0)         
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/python39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py"    line 328     in _fetch_row  
     return self._result.fetch_row(size  self._fetch_type)      
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 180: invalid start byte
```

The django html response additionally shows this:

```
Unicode error hint
The string that could not be encoded/decoded was: \n<p>�</p>\
```

Also the code snippet responsible for throwing the error is:

```
    exp = MyModel.objects.all()
    **for e in exp:** <-- this line is throwing the error
        #do something
```

Versions on both servers:

**EC2-1st** has:

```
Ubuntu 16.04.4

Django==1.11.2
mysqlclient==1.3.10
django-mysql==2.1.0

python3 --version
Python 3.5.2

mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.22, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

while
**EC2-2nd is a replica of EC2-1st with updates applied:**

```
Ubuntu 20.04.3

Django==3.2.6
mysqlclient==2.0.3
django-mysql==3.10.0

python3 --version
Python 3.9.5

mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.35, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Also, my local server is able to run fine with these versions of the tools:
[I had imported the RDS db locally with a local config that's close to the prod config to try debugging the issue].

```
Mac OS 11.5.2
Django==3.2.6
mysqlclient==2.0.3
django-mysql==3.10.0

Python 3.9.6

mysql  Ver 8.0.25 for macos11.3 on x86_64 (Homebrew)
```

What should I try?

Comment: See "black diamond" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 3):

The MySQL documentation [Connect-Time Error Handling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-connection.html#charset-connection-error-handling-connect-time) describes an issue when you use the MySQL 8.0 client library to connect to a MySQL 5.7 server with the utf8mb4 charset. The MySQL 8.0 client asks for the utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci collation, but the MySQL 5.7 server does not recognize that collation, so the server silently falls back to the latin1 charset with latin1_swedish_ci collation. Subsequently the server sends latin1 result sets, but the client thinks that it is receiving utf8mb4, which eventually results in a `UnicodeDecodeError`. As a workaround you have to explicitly `SET NAMES utf8mb4`. I created an issue [mysqlclient#504](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient/issues/504) to ask that the python client do that every time.

To confirm that the charset is incorrect after connecting, double check the server’s value of [`character_set_client`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_client) (the charset that statements are interpreted in), [`character_set_connection`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_connection) (the charset that statements are converted to), and [`character_set_results`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_results) (the charset that result sets are sent as). If they are `latin1` despite the client connecting as utf8mb4, then this bug probably was triggered.

```py
with con.cursor() as c:
  c.execute("show variables like 'character_set_%'")
  for row in c:
    print(row)
(b'character_set_client', b'latin1')
(b'character_set_connection', b'latin1')
(b'character_set_database', b'latin1')
(b'character_set_filesystem', b'binary')
(b'character_set_results', b'latin1')
(b'character_set_server', b'latin1')
(b'character_set_system', b'utf8')
(b'character_sets_dir', b'/usr/share/mysql/charsets/')
```

I believe that a workaround of the issue would be to do the following after connecting:

```py
# explicitly set connection charset to the same as MySQLdb.connect()
con.query("SET NAMES utf8mb4")
con.store_result()
```